# Meteor 0.8.3 app refusing connection to external mongo server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo replica set I connect to my meteor app using `MONGO_URL="mongodb://<user>:<pass>/host:27017/db"`. Recently after upgrading to meteor 0.8.3 it has strangely stopped working. I checked rolling back to 0.8.2 too, and it's not working there either, so I assume it's not something meteor has done and something might be wrong with my mongo server. I was able to deploy with same setup earlier. I can also run a mongo shell using `mongo -u <user> -p <password> host:port/db` from my machine and connect to remote server. Mongo user has read-write permissions.

Has anyone encountered this before? How can I connect with remote mongo instance and run my meteor app?

Below is the error that shows when I try to run meteor app with MONGO_URL set to remote mongo instance.

```
 /Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
W20140808-09:35:09.241(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20140808-09:35:09.241(5.5)? (STDERR)                             ^
W20140808-09:35:09.260(5.5)? (STDERR) MongoError: not authorized for query on celebvidy.system.dummy
W20140808-09:35:09.260(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
W20140808-09:35:09.261(5.5)? (STDERR)     at _.extend._nextObject (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:858)
W20140808-09:35:09.261(5.5)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.forEach (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:892)
W20140808-09:35:09.261(5.5)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.map (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:902)
W20140808-09:35:09.262(5.5)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.fetch (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:926)
W20140808-09:35:09.262(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Cursor.(anonymous function) [as fetch] (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:741)
W20140808-09:35:09.262(5.5)? (STDERR)     at MongoConnection.findOne (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:647)
W20140808-09:35:09.262(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Package (packages/collection-hooks/findone.js:23)
W20140808-09:35:09.263(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.collection.(anonymous function) [as findOne] (packages/collection-hooks/collection-hooks.js:102)
W20140808-09:35:09.264(5.5)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.findOne (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:238)
W20140808-09:35:09.264(5.5)? (STDERR)     - - - - -
W20140808-09:35:09.264(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.toError (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
W20140808-09:35:09.265(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:686:54
W20140808-09:35:09.265(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Cursor.close (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:969:5)
W20140808-09:35:09.265(5.5)? (STDERR)     at commandHandler (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:686:21)
W20140808-09:35:09.266(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1843:9
W20140808-09:35:09.266(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:445:41)
W20140808-09:35:09.266(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:468:18
W20140808-09:35:09.266(5.5)? (STDERR)     at MongoReply.parseBody (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
W20140808-09:35:09.267(5.5)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (/Users/charnjitsingh/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/4821944ffe/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:426:20)
W20140808-09:35:09.267(5.5)? (STDERR)     at emit (events.js:95:17)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Comment: Of course `MONGO_url` is just a typing error, right? :)

Comment: Do you have permissions to the `system` collection (shown `system.dummies`). This usually requires special privileges.

Comment: What do you mean by `system` collection? Do I need to set separate permissions for my_database.system collection? The user has full read/write access to `my_database`.

Comment: Ok I got mongo has restricted system collection. How can I change permissions to make the user be able to write to that collection?

Comment: Are you using the Houston package by chance? Just came across this bug: https://github.com/gterrono/houston/issues/205

Comment: @ChadKruse Yes it was houston. Thanks for the pointer, it was a life saver. Updating houston didn't help, I had to remove it altogether to get it deploying successfully. You've been a life saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed this is indeed a Houston-specific bug, as per https://github.com/gterrono/houston/issues/205.

The solution: Temporarily use a forked version of the repo that a) removes references to the 1.0.7 repo in the Houston's smart.json, and b) includes the commit that removed the dummy reference. I've confirmed this works on Modulus.

In your project's `smart.lock:`

Remove:
`"tag": "v1.0.7",`

Change:
`"git": "https://github.com/gterrono/houston.git",`

To:
`"git": "https://github.com/chadokruse/houston.git",` (or your own forked repo)

Then change:
`"commit": "a27e9e42d03764f09a6681a98945787fe1f6303d"`

To:
`"commit": "4f13530c2fafd1c3aac98f787a5598b3e04b150f"` (or the latest commit in your own forked repo)

Note: as soon as they update Houston to >1.0.7 you'll want to switch back.

If you're interested in the details of the bug fix, view the commit itself: https://github.com/gterrono/houston/commit/ecce96e6c8ed1b38f0d330c141135c47fc52ec58